# Getting first and last name through facebook ios SDK in conjunction with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm creating a simple iOS app using Azure Mobile Services as the backend and using Facebook for authentication. I followed a guide to set up everything and login via Facebook. However the only thing returned when logging in this way is an object with two properties similar to what is shown below

```
MSUser* user = {userId = @"Facebook:1234abcd",
mobileServiceAuthenticationToken = @"1234abdc567efg"}
```

I'm currently stuck trying to retrieve the users first and last name as the token I have is not a Facebook login token but a token for authenticating with my Azure backend. Is there anyway of getting the users name on the client side without having to have to open another facebook login window? (possibly using the Graph API) I found a way of fetching the info on the server side in a custom API however I would prefer to have it all figured out client side before saving user info to the server. (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx))

Edit: I can't find an equivalent *user.getIdentities* for use in iOS which provides the Facebook authentication token to use with the Graph API.

Answer (score 2):

The client SDK's User Object only contains the Mobile token, as you see. You need a separate Server API which exposes the customer information - the Server SDK has access to more information. You could do this as an API and when the user logs in for the first time, you save their info to the table, or you could create an API which queries Facebook each time.

There is a great blog post by Carlos on [Getting user information on Azure Mobile Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this w/o going to the server would be to use a client directed login instead of a server.

That allows you to use FB's SDK on the client to login via their tooling, get the user names, etc as needed, and then login to your mobile service by sending up your FB token instead.

```
[client loginWithProvider:@"microsoftaccount"
        token:@{@"access_token" : <fb token> }
   completion:^(MSUser *user, NSError *error) {

}];
```